# How to make a lightbox?: concept

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, lightbox

Imagine a lightbox with a beautiful picture inside it and a button somewhere near to navigate to the next picture...

When the user clicks the next button, JS does like so:

```
var Image = new Image();
Image.onload = getWidth;
Image.onerror = getFailure; 
Image.src = "http://somewebsite.mr/pics/4.png";
```

Then when the picture is loaded, JS goes into the getWidth function in order to find out the width of the picture:

```
w = this.width;  //height is not needed as CSS will adjust it correctly
```

After that, JS changes the width of the lightbox according to the width of the picture (with a bit add of paddings to make a border). And then, JS changes the src attribute of the picture, currently being shown in the lightbox, to the http://somewebsite.mr/pics/4.png. This changes the picture in the lightbox...

Is that the way lightboxes are built? This works, but I need ensure that it is cross-browser and works fine no matter what. Could you please tell me what you know about developing lightboxes? Is there another way of doing the job? Maybe you know some issues that could harm that program?

**EDIT:** My concern is whether there is something wrong with image preloading in the case of lightboxes or not. Would it be cross-browser? I know about the rest of the work. I just need to know how change pictures in a lightbox. I'm just new to the image preloading thing. Is it a main technique?

Comment: The code for e.g. jquery lightbox (http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) is less than 500 lines of code, with a lot of comments. It might confirm or disprove your understading about the concept.

Comment: Elzo, neither is it inventing nor reinventing. It's just coding.

Comment: This method is pretty much how ColorBox (http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html) does it. The author also has a lot of helpful comments in the code.

Comment: Thanks, fudgey, I will consider that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concept sounds about right. However, when creating a lightbox, there are numerous cross-browser issues to be aware of. I do not know of a manual or article that lists them all, but maybe you can find inspiration looking into the source code of other lightboxes. I personally have found Greg Neustaetter's [multi faceted lightbox](http://www.gregphoto.net/lightbox/) very easy to understand and customize.

Comment: Yes, Pekka, I would like to learn those numerous cross-browser issues.

Comment: Check out mflightbox's source code or, maybe even more interesting, the link mentioned in MYYN's comment above. I think well documented examples of existing lightboxes are the best you can get in terms of literature in this field.

Comment: Do you think there's something wrong with image preloading? What's so incapable about the way I mentioned?

Comment: Why would there be something wrong with image preloading? I said your concept sounds fine.